# How to resolve the error message: react-native-push-notification:extractReleaseAnnotations FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been struggling with this error.

When I run `yarn android` the build is successful, however when I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` I continue to receive this error.

```
> Task :react-native-push-notification:extractReleaseAnnotations FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:extractReleaseAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-push-notification:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download intellij-core-30.0.4.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.0.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.0.4/intellij-core-30.0.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.0.4/intellij-core-30.0.4.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.0.4.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.0.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.0.4/kotlin-compiler-30.0.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.0.4/kotlin-compiler-30.0.4.jar'.
            > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
```

[image]

Any help to get this fixed is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue by simply `path-to-project\android\build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() //<-- Moving this above maven
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
```

Hope this helps someone.